# Why is memory allocated with stackalloc not deallocated when it goes out of scope?

Tags: c#

When using `stackalloc` to allocate memory on stack in C#, the memory does not behave as you would normally expect from ordinary variables on the stack. The memory only gets deallocated when the method returns, contrary to normal variables which are deallocated when they go out of scope.

I am aware that this is not a bug, as it clearly written on the stackalloc page in the C# reference (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc), where it says "A stack allocated memory block created during the method execution is automatically discarded when that method returns."

I would like to know the reason behind this behavior, as it has given me a few headaches.

Consider this simple code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    int a = 0;

    //Do something with a
}
```

The code above should allocate 4 bytes for `a` on the stack, but that memory is freed as soon as the scope of the loop is left.

Then consider this:

```
unsafe
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int* a = stackalloc int[10];

        //Do something with a
    }
}
```

The code above now allocates 40 bytes every iteration of the loop.
That specific example can of course be optimized by moving the stackalloc out of the loop to only allocate it once, but that is not possible if the amount of data you need to allocate varies between iterations.

One could expect that the memory would be deallocated when it goes out of scope, just like ordinary variables on the stack, which is why I am interested in any possible reasons for this behavior.

Comment: What would you expect this code to do? https://gist.github.com/lassevk/f376751d1ada4ff873a03588907e46fe The purpose of `stackalloc` is to add a lightweight memory allocation model for performance-critical code, if you start adding lots of memory management around it, it is no longer lightweight.

Comment: One way of rewriting your code would be to separate out the body of the loop to a separate method, this would then get its own `stackalloc` frame and handle deallocation more in line with what you want.

Comment: Keep in mind that stack allocation is done by simply tacking on another set of bytes at the top (bottom) of the stack and moving the stack pointer. There's no *management* involved, so for instance, detecting that whatever `b` was pointing to when reassigning it is no longer needed, and then deallocating that, wouldn't be feasible without rearranging memory blocks and adjusting pointers to match. This is what GC is doing, stackalloc is meant to be much more lightweight and performant, *without* the burden of GC.

Comment: I think what you are questioning is a language design decision (born out of performance reasons), which is better answered by the people on the language design committee themselves. You can speak to them on GitHub, if you word this as a feature request for block scoped stackallocs at the [design repository](https://www.github.com/dotnet/csharplang), they will be happy to tell you why not.

Comment: @Daniel Your statement that memory for local variables is freed as soon as they go out of scope not accurate. A method's stack frame includes enough space to hold all the local variables* that the method will use. The space is all freed when the method returns. The only effect scope has on a variable is that its name cannot be referenced outside its declaring scope. So stackalloc actually works as should be expected.
*Not all "local" variables are stored on the stack in C#.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Putting the body of the loop in a seperate method was what I ended up doing, it had just not occurred to me before that it might have been necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allocated memory is automatically discarded when that method returns. So you could refactor your loop to call a method which does the stack allocation. That might bring the overhead of calling another method.

Let's see how does the stack allocation happen. The stack contains the return address of the caller and some data. When a function has to return then the VM/cpu pops the address from the stack and switches the Progrem Counter/Index to point there. If the function needs some temporary data it can use the area above the top of the stack as a temporary working memory. If no other functions are called, there is no need to deallocate anything. The area above the stack is considered to contain random garbage data. Upon function return the return address is popped from the top of the stack and the execution returns to the caller at the point it called the function.  The local variables are stored above the top of the stack. In machine  code, they are just offsets from the top.

Example of a stack for a normal function call:

```
 Param a - reserved and populated by the caller
 Param b
 Return address - top of the stack . Here points the stack pointer (SP). 
 local var1
 Local var2
 Local varx
```

The address of local var1 would be sp +size (ret address)
Var2 is the address of var1 + size of var1 and so forth. ( My explanation is simplistic, but you can see a real example here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames )

Since the compiler knows the variable sizes it can organize the offsets. The convention is that everything above the top of the stack can be used by the current function and everything below the top has to be preserved.
So allocating variables on the stack involves merely picking non-colliding offsets (above the top). Releasing the memory involves no actions. The fact that we return to the caller implies we have no more any claim on the area above the stack top.

Now if you are using the stack area above the top and need to call another function that might (and most probably will) corrupt your variables you have to temporarily move the stack top above the array your are using call that function and restore the SP before you return.

If you decide to dynamically allocate a block on the stack you have to maintain its current "shadow" top and the stack contents. Reserving more memory simply increases the shadow top of the stack. And when the function returns the shadow top is simply discarded and the memory is available again (instead of having a "shadow" top, most architectures will move the top of the stack and when returning either reduce it back to the original value or use built-in instructions to correct for that). Now you might be tempted to say that as you know the block size you can release it before returning. But then you might have a few blocks. You can keep a Linked list and release from the last. But releasing a block in the middle would require more advanced memory management and defeat almost all of the benefits of the quick stack memory allocation.

Comment: umm.. did you google translate this from somewhere? "sushi b contents"?

Answer (score 3):

Because it was modeled after the [alloca](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) function.

Or, at least, https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-334%201st%20edition%20December%202001.pdf sec 25.7 says

> All stack-allocated memory blocks created during the execution of a function member are automatically discarded when that function member returns. [Note:This corresponds to the `alloca` function, an extension commonly found C and C++ implementations. end note]

This behavior allows for code like

```
int*[] arr = new int*[values.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = stackalloc[values[i].Length];
    // do stuff
}

BulkProcess(arr);
```

The compiler could certainly use data flow and escape analysis to understand that it was a promoted allocation, but that is a very subtle thing to do, and if you confuse the analysis (e.g. `arr[i] = SkipLeadingZeros(arr[i])`) now you have really hard-to-find bugs.

The really tricky thing to do is

```
int* outerDelayed;

if (whatever)
{
    int* inner = stackalloc[something];
    ...
    outerDelayed = stackalloc[somethingElse];
}
else
{
    outerDelayed = notRelevant;
}

int* secondOuter = stackalloc[aThirdValue];
```

Where does `secondOuter` point? If `inner` was unallocated and `aThirdValue` was larger than `something` then reusing the same stack position as `inner` had will overlap `outerDelayed`'s buffer. Keeping track of how big holes in memory are and whether it's reasonable to use it is the job of a memory allocator (whether `malloc` or the GC), but is what `stackalloc` is trying to avoid.  (If `outerDelayed` also got unallocated when the `stackalloc` went out of scope, vs when the variable went out of lexical scope, there's now a very bad "dangling pointer" situation)

So, really, the easiest model is "all stackallocs are cumulative" in that they just slide `%RSP` every time, and let the function end in its normal flow of restoring the stack pointer to `%RBP`, simultaneously undoing the stack allocation for all fixed variables and all delayed stack allocations. This model is simple, which means that developers, reviewers, and bug-fixers can all understand it and apply it to the code in question.